# create a sqlite db on a specified directory

Tags: android, sqlite

Whatever is the android version, the path where a sqlite db is saved is always the same (/data/data/pack.name/databases/nameDb)?
If not, there's a way to save the entire db on a different location? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can choose where databases should be created, look at [openOrCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) methods. You can pass path into this method

But when your db inside `/data/data/pack.name/databases/` the Android system deals with security issues themselves and your db visible only for your app. Be carefull if you want to store your db on sdcard or at any other place.

Comment: So the default path is always the same? In this case there's no need to change the path, since I would do this just to be sure to define "an absolute" path where my Db get stored.

Comment: Yes default path already the same - inside your application folder